libav: listing only audio- or video-capable demuxers
FFMPEG API, libav, provides the following function to iterate over the available demuxers:
const AVInputFormat *av_demuxer_iterate(void **opaque);

I would like to know which of these demuxers are relevant for audio (ex.: alsa, s16le), which are for animated images (ex.: gif), video (ex.: hevc, mjpeg), and which are combined audio/video/... containers (mov, mp4 etc.).
But AVInputFormat (as of FFMPEG 6.1) does not seem to provide this information in any easily accessible way. Is there any way to get this information somewhere from the libav API ?

How do I ask a good question?. If you have a question tagged C++ we need source code written by you and you should aks one specific question about that. A question like : "How do I use library X" is best asked at the forum of said library

>  we need source code written by you
well, I can't write the source code because the type AVInputFormat does not seem to provide anything for this. But libav is vast and very widely used so I'm hoping that someone would know of a way like for the thousand other libav-related questions on stackoverflow.

This info isn't available except by examining the source code and seeing what types of streams may be exported.

You will need to do the following:

Research possible demuxers returned by av_demuxer_iterate.
This link could be useful: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html.

Research the purpose of each demuxer (Audio-Only, Video-Only, or Both).

Put your findings into a spreadsheet, associating each demuxer with Audio, Video, or Both.

(Optional) publish your findings online, to save your fellows the headache.

Declare a constant std::unordered_map to be accessible during the runtime of your program, containing the associations:


    const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> mediaTypes {
        {"mp4", "Both"},
        {"mp3", "Audio-Only"},
        {"gif", "Video-Only"}
        // more
    };

